# Insertion Sort algorithm array ordering and comparisons

Tags: sorting

I'm trying to figure out different scenarios in which insertion sort will have to make n(n-1)/2 comparisons (the worst case). The obvious case is when it the array is ordered in reverse (decreasing order). However, is it possible to have cases other than the reverse order case where the algorithm will still make the maximum possible number of comparisons?

For example, if we have the numbers 1, 2, and 3 in the array: 3, 2, 1 (worst case). Are there any other possible cases that would require the maximum number of comparisons to sort the array?

Comment: As insertion sort is stable, there are possibly infinitely many worst cases when *multiple elements* have the same 'comparison value'. e.g. if you are sorting 2-uplets where the first value is the one you compare. Else, the reversed array (sorted) is the worst case.

Comment: Interesting! But would it be possible to have other equivalent worst case situations (equivalent to the reverse order) with just single digit numbers like 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: No. This list can be $(1, 2, 3)$, $(2, 3, 1) $, $(3, 1, 2)$, $(2, 1, 3)$, $(1, 3, 2)$, $(3, 2, 1)$ (6 cases)= $\frac{3(3+2)}{2}$) and the worst case is $3, 2, 1$. This is because the worst case is when any item of the list is lesser-or-equal to any other item of the remaining of the list (at the right of that item). Which basically mean that the list is reverse-sorted (but not necessarily in a stable way).

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. But my question is in the case where you only have three numbers in the array that need to be sorted. 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Yes I understood, we are indeed talking of the same thing.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't notice your last edit! But the (2,3,1) case would also take the same number of comparisons as the (3,2,1) case in order to sort the list in increasing order - isn't that so?

Comment: Appart if I'm wrong, $2,3,1$ uses 2 comparisons when $3,2,1$ uses 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedantically, if it is in reverse order but you swap the first 2 elements (e.g. 2,3,1) you will also have to do n(n-1) comparisons. There are no other orderings that take this long.

Comment: And would the same rule apply for any number of elements? For example, if you have 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. Would 4, 5, 3, 2, 1 still be the only other order which would take an equivalent-to-worst-case number of comparisons? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, effectively the first comparison puts the 2 leftmost numbers in order, so the order they were in to start with is irrelevant (given you only care about comparisons, not swaps).